# "Error when extracting the ruleset parameter value from the request. at SignatureXMLBinding.deserialize" for the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I executed my rules deployed on the Business Rules for Bluemix using REST API. However, I see the following error messages:

> ilog.rules.res.decisionservice.IlrDecisionServiceException: Error when
>   extracting the ruleset parameter value from the request. at
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.binding.xml.SignatureXMLBinding.deserialize(SignatureXMLBinding.java:176)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.extractInParameters(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:954)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.execute(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:921)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.onMessage(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:843)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.handleRequest(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:750)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.doPost(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:737)
>   at
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.doPost(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:732)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had specified the content type in the request headers as XML:

```
 "Content-type" : "application/xml"
```

However, I passed the data in the JSON format. Once I fixed the content type as follows, I was able to execute the rules successfully.

```
 "Content-type" : "application/json"
```